# Zenlib error : undefined reference to Open function call which uses typedef

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a program which uses Zenlib

See below code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ZenLib/Ztring.h>
#include <ZenLib/File.h>

using namespace std;


int main () {
      ZenLib::File From;
      ZenLib::tstring tstr("/path/to/file");
      From.Open(tstr);
}
```

libzen.so is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Compile command

```
g++ -g tst1.cpp -o a.out -lpthread -lzen
```

I am getting below error

```
/tmp/cck5s6iO.o: In function `main':
/tmp/tst1.cpp:13: undefined reference to `ZenLib::File::Open(std::string const&, ZenLib::File::access_t)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Open declared as below

```
bool Open  (const tstring &File_Name, access_t Access=Access_Read);
```

tstring typedefed in Ztring.h as below

```
typedef std::basic_string<Char, std::char_traits<Char>, std::allocator<Char> > tstring;
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ LOL I thought it's new SO feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the ZenLib you are using is compiled as UNICODE.

Try the following code, it will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define UNICODE // must define this before including ZenLib's headers
#include <ZenLib/Ztring.h>
#include <ZenLib/File.h>

using namespace std;


int main () {
      ZenLib::File From;
      ZenLib::tstring tstr(L"/path/to/file"); // use unicode string literal
      From.Open(tstr);
}
```

Comment: Ohh man! How did you figure this out... Never got a whiff of such possibility.. Can you share anything which explains this kind of behavior... Bless you!

Comment: `vi /usr/include/ZenLib/Ztring.h` (where I saw the UNICODE thing), `vi /usr/include/ZenLib/Conf.h` (where I found the definition of the specific char type). Very flag it helped. Good luck!